# How to benchmark the fps of an animation in android?

Tags: android, animation, frame-rate

It would be really cool to benchmark how many times per second an animation actually gets drawn to the screen in an android app. Is there a way to do it?

ie. I can set an animation to run over a 250ms period, but I want to benchmark how smooth it is objectively.

Comment: ###See also
> [Calculating frames per second in a game](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/87304/calculating-frames-per-second-in-a-game)

Answer (score 0):

If you have a game loop running, you can calculate the framerate as follows:

FrameRate= 1000/LoopTime

Where LoopTime is the time it takes to execute an Update call and Draw call.