# Framerate of WM_PAINT

Tags: c, frame-rate, wndproc, wm-paint

Could anybody tell me please how can I get framerate of WM_PAINT message in frames per second? I'm trying to make a software renderer, and framerate is very important for debugging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question was asked previously [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/87304/calculating-frames-per-second-in-a-game). As an additional hint, you can use a dynamically allocated structure to store your FPS-related variables and use [SetWindowLongPtr](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644898%28VS.85%29.aspx) to store a pointer to this structure.

Comment: I know how to calculate FPS, I want to know how to retrieve frame generation time of WM_PAINT.

Comment: For that you could use [GetTickCount](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724408(v=vs.85).aspx).