# FPS Counter in Java

Tags: java, math, frame-rate

So, I'm making a game, and I want an FPS Counter, however I've got no clue what the math I should do behind it is. My previous counter worked, but it only updated every second due to the math. I want something constantly updating, but I just don't know how to make it. As far as I can tell, the easiest way to do this is to have a frame counter, and every frame it looks at the frames it's done so far and the time elapsed/time left and models the current frames for the rest of the second and displays that. That seems like a good theory, but I don't really know how to put it into practice. I know I'll need to use `System.currentTimeMillis` and such. Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

**EDIT 1**

Here's my FPS code here:

```
double getFPS(double oldTime) {
    double newTime = System.nanoTime();
    double delta = newTime - oldTime;

    double FPS = 1 / (delta * 1000);
    FPSOldTime = newTime;

    return FPS;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I implemented something like that in C++. I imagine it should work in Java also. The first line in the function has to use the Java time method tough.

```
double get_fps(double old_time) {
// Something like that in java  double new_time = System.getTime().nanoseconds();
    double delta = new_time - old_time;
    double fps = 1 / (delta * 1000);
    old_time = new_time;
    return fps;
};
```

Format the double with something like this: `%2.0f`

PS. (Run it in your game loop and the old time has to be initialized before game loop. You will be changing it via a reference.)

Comment: Where would I get `new_time`?

Comment: Its in the comment in my answer.. ```double new_time = System.nanoTime();```

Comment: Try it with System.currentTimeMillis and nanotime, see which one does the trick in Java.

Comment: ```double newTime = System.nanoTime();```   And in case you prefer CAPS_LOCK NEWTIME then here is the code for that: ```double NEWTIME = System.nanoTime();```

Comment: Let me know if you need more help in changing variable names.

Comment: Oh no, sorry, I meant oldTime, sorry. I do know how to change variable names, I just did a typo.

Comment: As I sayd. Before you initialize your game loop, you make a variable oldTime which till have System.nanoTime(); in it. Now every time you call the getFps() method in your game loop you also pass this oldTime to it. The getFps() will update the old time via reference.

Comment: So I updated my OP code but this returns massive numbers with E's in them, such as 8.208860803603308E-12

Comment: Try to use ```System.currentTimeMillis();  ``` instead of nanoTime then.

Comment: Seems you have done something wrong then. You can look into other answers. Maybe they explain the same thing better than I do :)    (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/87304/calculating-frames-per-second-in-a-game)